# Force YARN to deploy Spark tasks across all slaves

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I've been deploying the SparkPi example on an 8-node cluster. It would appear that the tasks associated with the example are not being deployed to all nodes in the cluster, even though the cluster is under-utilized (no other jobs running).

Here's how I am starting the SparkPi example:

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 7 $SPARK_HOME/lib/spark-examples-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar 100000
```

However, when I look at which nodes are being utilized, this is what I see:
[image: hadoop cluster]

I have a feeling this is because I'm using the `CapacityScheduler` in the resource manager. Here is my `yarn-site.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
      <value>master.cluster</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
      <value>master.cluster:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
      <value>master.cluster:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:8088</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
      <value>master.cluster:8031</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
      <value>master.cluster:8033</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
      <value>master.cluster:8033</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
      <value>/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*, /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*</value>
    </property>

    <property>
    <description>
      Number of seconds after an application finishes before the nodemanager's
      DeletionService will delete the application's localized file directory
      and log directory.

      To diagnose Yarn application problems, set this property's value large
      enough (for example, to 600 = 10 minutes) to permit examination of these
      directories. After changing the property's value, you must restart the
      nodemanager in order for it to have an effect.

      The roots of Yarn applications' work directories is configurable with
      the yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs property (see below), and the roots
      of the Yarn applications' log directories is configurable with the
      yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs property (see also below).
    </description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec</name>
    <value>600</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

How can I tweak YARN so that it deploys tasks across *all* nodes?

Answer (score 1):

1. An application manager should not take up much resources. Declaring to assign up too 100% is really to much. I do not know what good you have accomplished here (suspecting not any).
2. You *should* prefer to run as many as possible tasks on the same node for as long as resources are available. This will avoid overhead of serializing and sending data over the cluster's internal network. You should also prefer to run as many as possible tasks within the same executor instance to allow memory sharing.
3. when using the capacity scheduler in it's default setup, it calculates resources only based on memory footprint, and will ignore the CPU footprint. you declare the memory footprint as part of your Spark Configuration and Parametersfor the Driver, Application Manager (am), and executor. See the spark manuals for more detailed information, particularly [the part about running Spark on Yarn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) and [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). The specific spark configurations are:

   1. spark.yarn.am.memory (config)
   2. spark.driver.memory (config)
   3. spark.executor.memory (config)

Note that the settings for number of cores are also important, but more used by spark itself rather than by yarn (unless you change the way it calculates the resource utilization).

If you can run your single job requiring 32 CPU cores on a single node, then first of all congratulations on your nice system, but this is probably the way you want to run it!

Comment: I'm actually using the cluster for neural network training and it's not a production-facing system. In this case the more I can push the cluster, the better. Does that help with context? Otherwise, completely agree.

Comment: Cram as much as possible tasks under one executor. Don't know the underlying software architecture of a neural network, but I am sure it is going to help you in performance. If it were a traditional spark job, I would know to tell you that your sort and shuffle faze is going to be super fast.

Comment: @YoYo how to pack tasks more dense in Spark? For example, I have 10 executors with 5 cores each, and a job with 5 partitions. In the executors tab I see each executor executes only one task, instead of 5 tasks in one single executor.

Comment: @haodemon most likely, it will evenly distribute taks over executors like what you are seeing. My suggestion would be to start up only one executor for your job. Actually, only 5 partitions seems so less? Are they huge data chunks that can be split in smaller partitions? Parallelization works better with smaller partitions and number of partitions a multiple of number of executors. It is ok to queue up partitions in consecutive tasks.

Comment: @YoYo I'm trying to see if shuffle could be reduced if tasks are spawned in a single executor so that memory is shared between these tasks. I see the tasks are spawned on different nodes, but would like to achieve some kind of locality here

Answer (score 0):

The answer was fairly simple, in `$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop/capacity-scheduler.xml` you can change the default `0.1` to `1`:

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
      Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run 
      application masters i.e. controls number of concurrent running
      applications.
    </description>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Although the cluster will only allow one master application to run at a time (my preference), it will utilize the entire cluster.